# What is the best way to fork wordpress git repository?

Tags: wordpress, git

I am staring new Wordpress project. I want to use WP Github repository as a base and push it to my own repository. But also I want to save link to original WP repository, switch branches on it and pull new updates. What is the best strategy for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set up the official repository as `official` and your personal repository as `personal` or `origin`:

```
git remote add official <official_remote>
```

then

```
git remote add personal <personal_remote_path>
```

or

```
git remote rm origin ;# remove the current origin, presumably the official one
git remote add origin <personal_remote_path>
```

You can then use `git fetch official` and `git merge` to pull in updates from the official repository, or you can set the proper upstream tracking branches with `git checkout`. For example:

```
git fetch official
git merge official/master
```

or

```
git checkout -b official-master --track official/master
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have one strange thing. When I try to clone my repository on the other machine, I have only one personal remote.

Comment: That is expected behavior. Remotes are stored locally. You'll have to set up the remotes for each clone you make, but fortunately you only have to do it once.

Answer (score 1):

Just get a fork of the WP repository on GH then clone your fork not the WP repository. Then you can add official as a remote `git remote add WP <the wp repo link>`. If you want your own work private however just clone the WP repository and create a new remote for your private repo `git remote add private <repo link>`.

You should in my opinion branch of your work off master and keep master in sync with WP repo. So `git checkout -b mybranch` will create a new branch based on master. When you want to sync your master you should just `git fetch` and then `git merge WP/master` on your own master.

You should rebase your branch on master when you update it with `git rebase master mybranch`

WP through out the whole commands is an alias for the official branch remote name if you cloned the WP repo it would be origin